# Cmd and mmc with whitespace paths

Tags: windows-7, cmd, whitespace, shortcut, mmc

I'm trying to create a shortcut to an .msc file, but I want to open the file with another account.
The closest I've come is:

```
runas /savecred /user:PATHy\USERx "mmc \\folder\subfolder\folder with space\file.msc"
```

and it works as long as there aren't any white spaces in the path name. I know that I should escape spaces with "" (quotations) in Windows but the `runas` command already require the `mmc` command to be escaped. Does anybody know how I can achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `runas` documentation (`runas /?`) shows how to do this as one of it's examples:

```
REM use backslash to escape your quotes, e.g., \"file with spaces\"
runas /env /user:user@domain.microsoft.com "notepad \"my file.txt\""
```

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the short file name of the directory

type

DIR /x \folder\subfolder

Take note of the short file for the directory with spaces
Then use this short name in your command.
For example

```
runas /savecred /user:PATHy\USERx "mmc \\folder\subfolder\folder~1\file.msc"
```

Comment: Thank you! I found the answer from RB. to be more along the lines of what I wanted even though this also works.